# What is the real meaning of 'this' in Java?

Tags: java, this

I looked at a [Why can't I use the keyword "this" when referring to fields in static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593420/why-cant-i-use-the-keyword-this-when-referring-to-fields-in-static-methods)

and thought that accessing static members through a reference variable is ok, but using `this` to access such members is not okay. Look at the code below.

```
static int month; 

public static void setMonth(int x)
{ 
Date date = new Date();
date.month = x;  //fine, why ?
    this.month = x;  //compiler error, why ?
}
```

It clearly shows that `this` is not the same as a reference variable. If that is so, then what is it really? I need to understand the true meaning of `this` to understand why it cannot be accessed from a static context.

**Please don't give me links to random blogs or oracle tutorials which say that `this` can't be used from a static context - I already know that.** I want to look beyond that and understand why it can't be used.

Code in linked question -

```
public class Date
{

static int month; 

public static void setMonth(int x)
{ 
 this.month = x;  //compiler error
}

public static int getMonth()
{
 return month;  //compiles just fine, no error
}

}
```

Comment: There is no `this` in anything static as youre dealing with a class, and not an instance of the class. `this` only refers to an instance.

Comment: `this` refers to the *current instance* of that class.  In static context, there is no current instance of the class, by definition.  As a result, `this` cannot be called in static context.

Answer (score 3):

When you call a non-static method, e.g. myObject.myMethod(), the compiler adds an extra secret parameter valued 'myObject' which is available inside the method as 'this'.

When you call a static method, e.g. MyClass.myStaticMethod(), there is no object to assign the secret parameter's value to, so there is no extra secret parameter, so 'this' can't have a value inside the static method.

Comment: EJP - Is this an analogy ? If not, then please show me the source of this information.

Comment: @skyscraper Not analogy, fact. Common knowledge among compiler writers. Have a look at any Java byte code for proof.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void setMonth(int x)
{ 
 this.month = x;  //compiler error
}
```

`this` refers to the current object instance. No such thing in a static method, as a static method is associated to the class as a whole, not any specific instance.

So you cannot use `this` at all in a static method.

That the field you refer to (`month`) is actually a static field not an instance field does not matter. You would not have needed `this` here, but if you try to access it, the compiler will stop you.

```
public static int getMonth()
{
 return month;  //compiles just fine, no error
}
```

`month` is a static field. Just like the static method, it belongs to the class itself, and does not need an instance to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

It is really very simple, once you understand what `static` means.

The `this` keyword (when used that way) means "the current object".

When you declare a method as `static`, you are saying that the method will always be called without nominating a specific object as the current object.  So, when you are in a `static` method, there is no "current" object ... and as a logical consequence you can't use `this`, because it makes no sense.

There is only a "current" object if you are in an instance method or a constructor<sup>1</sup>.  In the former case, the "current" object is the one that you called the method on.  In the latter case it is the object you are creating.

---

<sup>1 ... or an instance initializer block</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, `this` can indeed be used to reference a static field, provided it is done in non-static code so that `this` exists. It just can't be done where `this` does not exist.

```
public class Test {
  static int month;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().setMonth(5);
    System.out.println(month);
  }
  public void setMonth(int x)
  { 
      this.month = x;
  }
}
```

Comment: And it is frowned upon and generates a compiler warning (at least with some compilers).

Comment: As it should be. That is just like any other reference expression.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `date.month = x;` is EXACTLY equivalent to `Date.month = x;` and that's what the compiler does at compile time. What you put on the left side actually doesn't matter. Accessing a static field or method through a reference is highly discouraged for this reason -- it looks as if the thing to the left of the dot matters, but it is not; only the compile-time type of the expression matters. Consider

```
(new Date()).month = x;
((Date)null).month = x;
// suppose SubDate is a subclass of Date, with its own static "month" field
((Date)new SubDate()).month = x;
```

All of the things above do the EXACT same thing.

So when you say

> and thought that accessing static members through a reference variable
>   is ok

Accessing static members through a reference variable should never be used. Because it is a huge illusion that has lead to numerous misconceptions and bugs; and probably should never have been allowed in Java.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the bugs caused by accessing static members through a reference variable ?

Comment: @skyscraper: for example, often on code samples you will see `Thread.currentThread().sleep(...);` to sleep the current thread for a period of time. Then you might be tempted to do `someOtherThread.sleep(...);` to sleep some other thread. But actually `Thread.sleep()` is a static method, and both pieces of code do the same thing -- sleep the current thread. Always writing it as `Thread.sleep(...);` will make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `this` refers to the current object instance.

You cannot use it from a `static` context because there is no instance by definition of the concept of `static` in java. A `static` method can be accessed by *all instances*.

An example

```
public static final class MyClass {

    public static final class MyInnerClass {

        public void doStuff() {
            System.out.println(this.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyInnerClass toString.";
        }
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
        new MyInnerClass().doStuff();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass toString.";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new MyClass().doStuff();
}
```

Output

```
MyClass toString.
MyInnerClass toString.
```

So the `this` in the `doStuff` method of `MyClass` refers to the instance of `MyClass` from within which `doStuff` was called.

The `this` in `MyInnerClass` does not refer to the instance of `MyClass` but rather to the instance of `MyInnerClass` from which its `doStuff` was called.

`this` **always** refers to the instance of the object from within which the keyword is used. If there is no instance, as is the case in a `static` method, the `this` keyword cannot be used.